# How can I have a Timestamp created in a column when the state of a field in another column is set to a specific status?

Tags: google-appsheet

How can I have a Timestamp created in a column when the state of a field in another column is set to a specific status?, ie. "In-Progress"?

I have a column for "Status", there are buttons to press when the job is "in progress" and "completed".
I would like a date/timestamp to automatically populate in the "time started" column in that same row when the activity is set to "In-Progress", then when it is changed to "completed" I'd like a date/time stamp to populate in the "time completed" column in that row.

Status is column 6, Time Started Column 7, Time Completed is Column 8

I tried writing a script but can't seem to get the logic right for anything beyond setting the current time when a cell changes status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Track changes using Change column types](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106528?hl=en&sjid=3734017283386800770-SA)